# How to get the index of each item that is null in a List<T> via Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

Is there a way to get the index of each object in a List that is null?

For example:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1", null, "2", null, "3" };
```

Is it possible to get the information that list[1] and list[3] is null?
In the best case I would get another list that provides me all the indexes that are null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the simplest option would probably be:

```
var nullIndexes = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                      .Where(pair => pair.value == null)
                      .Select(pair => pair.index)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: it works, but it's slow because we have to iterate the list many times.

Comment: @Khanh: Nope... This will work even with input which can only be evaluated once.

Comment: it looks to me there is 1 loop for Select, another loop for Where, and another loop for Select, No?

Comment: @Khanh: Each of those is chained to the result of the previous one though - I think you might benefit from reading up on LINQ's streaming and lazy evaluation model...

Comment: thanks for your comment. I'm looking for a documentation now. From what I understand from your comment, each iteration will perform all 3 predicates in `select`, `where`, `select`.

Comment: @Khanh: Sort of. Search for my Edulinq blog post series for a lot more information :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
list.Select((item,i) => new { index = i, item=item })
    .Where(p=>p.item == null)
    .Select(item=>item.index);
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IyFVpa)

Comment: How does that provide the indexes of elements with a null value?

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I was rushing for providing working sample. Corrected it now.

Comment: Okay..  Although you now have a statement which doesn't do anything, because you're ignoring the return value. I believe my answer is more useful - and does exactly what was asked for, in terms of providing a new list.